# Selenium - login and password in url generate errors

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I need help with the following problem with **selenium-webdriver**:

I have an url like this:

```
http://my-web-site/index-app
```

And I need to send my user and password in that url.

```
user: CAB\AB70123
pass: C2018+
```

Then, I have the final url:

```
http://CAB\AB70123:C2018+@my-web-site/index-app
```

But when I execute my java application

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\selenium-drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
webDriver.get("http://CAB\AB70123:C2018+@my-web-site/index-app");
```

I have the the following error trace:

```
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'SOME-PC', ip: '172.25.128.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:29950/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 907a8bc9-a3a8-4e3d-93e7-fb05b3744ba2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:273)
    at com.occoa.selenium.App.main(App.java:16)
```

**Update**

I've changed to selenium-ie-driver v2.21.0 and already don´t see the error but when I execute in the url see the following

```
http://cab/AB70123:C2018+@my-web-site/index-app
```

Comment: Please try IE driver with 32 bit.

Comment: I have tried with IE driver 32 bit :(

Comment: Please downgrade selenium version . This type of expectation occurs because of version issues only

Comment: Update the question with your _cpde trials_ and the _error stack trace_